# Newspaper Theme Categories Not Displaying Posts: Troubleshooting Needed

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, categories

Dear Stack Overflow community,

I am experiencing an issue. I have installed the Newspaper theme, and now the newly created categories are not displaying the posts within them. Please check the screencast video for a detailed explanation of the problem: https://screenrec.com/share/UoutJI8p5y

I am trying to display the categories on on the home page and other places.